# Can't clear cache as drupal_test.cache_filter doesn't exist

Tags: caching

I run into an issue, I can't clear the cache anymore as I get this error:

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 La table 'drupal_test.cache_filter' n'existe pas: TRUNCATE {cache_filter} ; Array ( ) in cache_clear_all() (line 168 of C:\wamp\www\drupal-7.41\includes\cache.inc).`

I've read a few posts on stackoverflow with the same problem but different table and I wonder if I can try to apply the same solution (I don't know much sql so I'm not sure if I can just copy and paste from any solution as I don't want to make things worse). Some solutions seem to be dropping and recreating a table called [cache_field](https://www.drupal.org/node/2144205#comment-9293437), others [cache_rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2097037#comment-7898929) but I couldn't find anything for that specific table drupal_test.cache_filter. Do you reckon it's worth trying both of them, or does anybody have another solution? Last time I had this problem - I can't remember if it was the same table though - I ended up reinstalling the whole drupal, and I'd like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run drush rr in advance? It would clean up your registry of modules an quite often fixes those issues.

Maybe some module got moved or if removed try to figure out what has been removed, re-install it and try again.

Comment: hi thanks, no I don't use drush. As far as I know, no module has been removed. Do you think that if I drop and rebuild the table in the error that would help? Like http://pastebin.com/YDWXD2KR

Comment: Recreating the table will definitely fix that specific error @jazzo, and it has the same structure as all the other cache tables so duplicating is all you need. Trouble is, unless your main problem is that someone or thing simply deleted that table, it's probably going to be the tip of the iceberg

Comment: @Clive oh yes sure, I appreciate that. The funny thing is that the table node - if that's what's it's called - is still there in phpmyadmin, but when i click on it it says it's empty. As I said the error appeared after I removed some content from a template - and then I put it back again after seeing the error - so it might be that something got deleted as a consequence of that. In any case, let me try and I'll report back

Comment: OK that has worked, I can clear the cache OK now